# how to pass http api data to anther page?

Tags: flutter, httprequest

I was building a demo application for a store (not a specific one) and I got the data from an online JSON file through http requests, is it possible to pass the data to another file?

I tried to pass the data using an object from the where I extracted the data and using sharedPreferences too expecting to pass the data to the other screen and display it, but the actual output was nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can share data from one page to another page using arguments property of push method

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("routeName",arguments: data);
```

to extract this data in the second page use this

```
ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: what you want to know?